# Historical reason for function keys having non-consecutive key sequences in xterm

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, xterm, history, terminal-emulator

I'm using gnome-terminal as my terminal emulator, which sets `TERM=xterm-256color`. The key sequences sent when pressing the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, … are as printed by

```
$ infocmp -L1 | grep _f | sort -V
key_f1=\EOP,
key_f2=\EOQ,
key_f3=\EOR,
key_f4=\EOS,
# gap 4
key_f5=\E[15~,
# gap 5
key_f6=\E[17~,
key_f7=\E[18~,
key_f8=\E[19~,   # no gap 4 here
key_f9=\E[20~,
key_f10=\E[21~,
# gap 5
key_f11=\E[23~,
key_f12=\E[24~,
# gap 4
key_f13=\E[1;2P,
key_f14=\E[1;2Q,
key_f15=\E[1;2R, # no gap 5 here
key_f16=\E[1;2S,
# gap 4
key_f17=\E[15;2~,
# gap 5 
key_f18=\E[17;2~,
…
```

I wonder why there are gaps (marked with `# gap …`) in the key sequences. The "missing" key sequences (for instance `\E[16~`) are not used otherwise, as indicated by `infocmp -L1 | grep -F '\E[16~'`).

Modern keyboards group function keys into groups of four keys each, so a gap between these groups is understandable. Some historic keyboards grouped some of their function keys into groups of five keys each, so a gap between those groups is understandable too. However, the gaps are sometimes (but not always) between groups of 4 and sometimes (but not always) between groups of 5 keys, which causes some of the function keys to build groups of just 1 or 2 keys – I haven't heard of any keyboard with such a layout.

**What is the reason for these key sequences?** Compatibility between keyboard layouts (with groups of 4 or 5 function keys each) seems unlikely, as gaps from the one layout would break the other layout and vice versa.

Comment: See https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-PC-Style-Function-Keys

Comment: The VT100 only had four function keys, at the top of the four column numeric keypad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnome-terminal copies the most commonly-used keyboard configuration of xterm.

In turn, xterm uses key assignments to match DEC VT220, e.g., its [LK201 keyboard](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/vt320-keyboard.jpg).  Those account for most of the gaps.  The different encoding used in F1-F4 and F13-F16 are not from the VT220.  F1-F5 on a VT220 are *local* function keys by default (normally do not send anything to the host).

Rather, the F1-F4 codes are the [top row of the VT100 numeric keypad](https://deskthority.net/wiki/images/c/cd/VT100_Top.JPG) which did not fit into the X keyboard configuration because *NumLock* was reserved.  F13-F16 adapt that workaround to xterm's modified function keys (e.g., where the *shift* ***modifier*** causes xterm to send the `;2` part of the key sequence).

Some of the VT220 keys have other names (e.g., F16 is the *Help* key), but xterm has no use for those names (because they are application-specific).  If it did use those names in the terminal description, there would be more gaps in the listing.  But the VT220-specific gaps relate to the groups of function-keys on the DEC hardware terminal.

```
$ infocmp -L1 | grep _f | sort -V
key_f1=\EOP,
key_f2=\EOQ,
key_f3=\EOR,
key_f4=\EOS,
# gap 4
key_f5=\E[15~,
# gap 5
key_f6=\E[17~,
key_f7=\E[18~,
key_f8=\E[19~,   # no gap 4 here
key_f9=\E[20~,
key_f10=\E[21~,
# gap 5
key_f11=\E[23~,
key_f12=\E[24~,
# gap 4
key_f13=\E[1;2P,
key_f14=\E[1;2Q,
key_f15=\E[1;2R, # no gap 5 here
key_f16=\E[1;2S,
# gap 4
key_f17=\E[15;2~,
# gap 5 
key_f18=\E[17;2~,
…
```

The xterm-r6 terminal description does not have these changes for F1-F4 (and F13-F16), but shows the expected gaps:

```
> infocmp -L1 xterm-r6 | grep key_f | sort -V
        key_f1=\E[11~,
        key_f2=\E[12~,
        key_f3=\E[13~,
        key_f4=\E[14~,
        key_f5=\E[15~,
...
        key_f6=\E[17~,
        key_f7=\E[18~,
        key_f8=\E[19~,
        key_f9=\E[20~,
        key_f10=\E[21~,
        key_f11=\E[23~,
        key_f12=\E[24~,
        key_f13=\E[25~,
        key_f14=\E[26~,
...
        key_f15=\E[28~,
        key_f16=\E[29~,
...
        key_f17=\E[31~,
        key_f18=\E[32~,
        key_f19=\E[33~,
        key_f20=\E[34~,
        key_find=\E[1~,
```

(gnome-terminal isn't actually a VT220 emulator because it lacks almost all of the character-set features, but rather an xterm-imitator).